# How to fire a pathTransition.setOnFinished event in JavaFX?

Tags: java, animation, events, javafx

I have a "flyingObject" (some shape that moves around on pathes) and some code in an event-handler of the PathTransition.setOnFinished, that I want to also execute from another class. Accessing the pathTransition is no Problem and I know that it is an ActionEvent, but how do I specifically fire the setOnFinished.
So far I have this, which does not work:

```
Event.fireEvent(flyingObjectA.getPathTransition(),new ActionEvent());
```

Thanks for any advice. I know, the code could just be moved to a method which is called then, but I'm also interested how to fire this event manually.

Comment: `flyingObjectA.getPathTransition().getOnFinished().handle(new ActionEvent())`???

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have some code that you want to execute when the path transition finishes, but also want to execute under other circumstances? Why not just move that code to another method, and call the method whenever you need to?

Comment: James, you are of course right. Nevertheless I'm interested in this question. I edited my question.